# Testing Chrome extension update transition code using auto-update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension in the chrome store published as V1. I would like to publish V2. However, first I want to test the automatic update scenario where a user goes from V1->V2 via automatic update, to ensure that internal state for the extension is not broken by the updates.

Is there any way to test automatic updates? I would prefer an officially supported methodology, but I'm really just looking for a way to test that my update code works with automatic updates.